# Does train and test score change depending on the magnitude of values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

There's no specific code for this.

Right now, I have a logistic regressor with target column is `is_promoted` (boolean) with 0's and 1's. When I find the train and test accuracy and MSE, they are between 0 and 1.

I have a different model, it's a linear regressor. The target column is 'resale_price` with values 10,000 and up. When I find the train and test accuracy, they are negative, and sometimes go past -1. And their MSEs are also at least 5 digits long.

What I am wondering is,

1. In my logistic regressor, the values are 1 digit long, whereas my linear regressor has values 5-6 digits long. Do bigger numbers produce bigger MSE?
2. My linear regressor train and test MSE are like 100,000. Could something be wrong with my data preparation?

Answer (score 0):

MSE is not a suitable metric for logistic regression. In a machine learning context, logistic regression predicts membership of a binary class based on the data input variables. As you state in the question, the predicted class can only be 1 or 0. The formula for MSE is

[image]

Clearly, when both the predicted and actual Y values are only either 0 or 1, this formula doesn't make sense.

Metrics that make more sense for logistic regression as a classifier algorithm are classifier-specific metrics, such as accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity (see [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)).

Linear regression is a regression algorithm, and so predicts a continuous outcome. In this situation, MSE is a suitable metric (along with R-squared, RMSE, MAE, and others).

And in answer to your second question, MSE is dependent on scale, so without further context, this question cannot be answered. A scaleless metric for linear regression is R-squared, which assesses the correlation of the predicted values versus the actual values, with `R-Squared = 1` being perfect fit.